This command, host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.sopranos.org.arpa gives me this error. Host _ldap._tcp.sopranos.org.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
I'm doing all this on a VvirtualBox guest OS, taking snapshots before each and every change. I'm trying to set up a domain controller. Everything is updated. (Always:)
I'm following these instructions .
Each and every time I get to this same spot, and I get the same results.
sudo smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator -c 'ls'
Password for [SOPRANOS\Administrator]:
  .                                   D        0  Wed Oct  9 15:15:08 2024
  ..                                  D        0  Wed Oct  9 15:15:08 2024

        50770432 blocks of size 1024. 36740828 blocks available

At this point I'm good. At the very next step, I'm not. I've restored snapshots 4 times, with the same result.
host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.sopranos.org.arpa
Host _ldap._tcp.sopranos.org.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

No A records either. I tried a few things I found on google, and I couldn’t even get onto the web afterwards. I could ping 8.8.8.8, but not google.com.
sudo kinit Administrator
[sudo] password for richie:  
kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "SOPRANOS.ORG.ARPA" while getting initial credentials

My hosts file:
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.206   ra.sopranos.org.arpa ra

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Do I even need that "stuff" for IPv6? I disabled it. Don't need it, don't want it. It just clutters things up.
krb5.conf

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = SOPRANOS.ORG.ARPA

    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

(I've tried dns_lookup_realm = true to no avail.)
[realms]
SOPRANOS.ORG.ARPA = {
    default_domain = sopranos.org.arpa
}

[domain_realm]
    ra = SOPRANOS.ORG.ARPA

resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search sopranos.org.arpa

smb.conf

# Global parameters
[global]
    bind interfaces only = Yes
    dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
    interfaces = lo enp0s3
    netbios name = RA
    realm = SOPRANOS.ORG.ARPA
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = SOPRANOS

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/sopranos.org.arpa/scripts
    read only = No

richie@ra:~$ hostname -s
ra

richie@ra:~$ hostname -d

sopranos.org.arpa

richie@ra:~$ hostname -f
ra.sopranos.org.arpa

richie@ra:~$ hostname -i
192.168.1.206

richie@ra:~$ hostname -I
192.168.1.206 2601:205:4484:fb50:799:3181:ccd0:bbae 2601:205:4484:fb50:a00:27ff:fe24:e774 

Did you see that? IPv6 just clutters things up.

If you use the .arpa TLD then I think you need to use one of the reserved subdomains like .home (per the link that you say you are following) - see for example Best choice for private/home network TLD? Overlap with mDNS?. OTOH if you are using your own purchased domain you should perhaps omit the .arpa suffix altogether? See also Top level domain/domain suffix for private network?

Well, I wish for the sake of others with the same issue, I could say what fixed it. Sadly, like i say, 'tis a virtual machine and I took snapshots every time I made any change, what-so-ever.
After doing it over, and over, and over, I finally got it right.
Even though, I was copying and pasting, I must have missed something somewhere. Probably get a little cross-eyed, after a while.
And no WAY I was giving up that organized crime family, the sopranos:)
